# Customising twitter-widget api 1.1

Tags: twitter

I want to customise twitter widget with new API. Here example: http://jsfiddle.net/br3t/jQzXK/

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-theme="dark"  href="https://twitter.com/snkgames"  data-widget-id="314861924259078144" width="800" height="50" data-chrome="noheader nofooter" data-border-color="#cc0000" lang="RU">Tweets by @snkgames</a>
```

I need to remove avatars, make font smaller. Also, sizing-styles is not allowed. How can I fix it?

Comment: I am currently reading through the documentation to make my new one look like my old one.

Answer (score 1):

I found a website that helps a lot here: http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/

There is also documentation here for embedding. It gives a list of client side options to override the server side stuff
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

Comment: Very good tutorials, really spells it out for you! Might be a little long winded but it's worth it. This should be the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found this...Add custom CSS to the Twitter 1.1 Embed Widget;

[Customize Twitter 1.1](http://kevinburke.github.io/customize-twitter-1.1/)

Comment: This is good and a big help but does anyone know how to hide the images that will appear in the twitter feed?

Comment: @jelly46 No. do you know ? (now)

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion of Twitter dev, maybe it could help
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11386?page=1